# PHP Email Server

Tags: php, python, linux, email

How can I program my own email server in PHP, that listens for email and forward the messages to a URL?

Is python more recommended for this?

Regards,

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? If you dont know how to search google - you dont stand a chance in doing anything like this!

Comment: adding to @Andy Paton, you can find a lot of open source mail servers as a base, if you are REALLY need to create something very special. look here for the list:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_mail_servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use an already developed email server software. There are some really well tested ones out there.
You do not need to reinvent the wheel. Save you that trouble! You may use one of the following

- [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/)
- [sendmail](http://www.sendmail.org)
- there are so many other solutions out there (igor milla mentioned a wikipedia site which list more smtp servers)